# How can I create a chart/plot in JavaScript with just a SINGLE calculated number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plot, charts

I was wondering how I can incorporate a plot or chart into JavaScript to plot ONE number. It's kind of a just an entertaining piece I'm doing. I eventually want it to be a "stress test" with the number that is calculated from my equation. Any idea on how to do this?

Here is my jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/avanhout13/em5vq8Ld/

```
HTML:

    Calculate Stress

<FORM name="stress">
<A NAME="stress"></A>

Calculate Stress<br>

Enter Value<br>

Force: <INPUT TYPE="text" SIZE="7"  maxlength="15" NAME="force">

            <SELECT NAME="forceunits">
    <OPTION VALUE="1" selected>Newtons</OPTION>
    <OPTION VALUE="0.00001">Dyne</OPTION>
    <OPTION VALUE="0.00980665 ">Gram Force</OPTION>
    <OPTION VALUE="1">Kgs-Meter/sec^2</OPTION>
    <OPTION VALUE="9.80665 ">Kilograms Force</OPTION>
    <OPTION VALUE="4448.22161526">Kip</OPTION>   
    <OPTION VALUE=" 4.44822162 ">Pound Force</OPTION>    
    <OPTION VALUE=" 0.138254954376 ">Poundal</OPTION>    
    </SELECT>
<br>

Area:     <INPUT TYPE="text" SIZE="7"  maxlength="15" NAME="area">

            <SELECT NAME="areaunits">
    <OPTION VALUE="1" selected>Metre^2</OPTION>
    <OPTION VALUE="100">Are</OPTION>
    <OPTION VALUE="1e-28">Barn</OPTION>
    <OPTION VALUE="0.0001">Centimetre^2</OPTION>
    <OPTION VALUE="0.09290304">Foot^2</OPTION>
    <OPTION VALUE="10000">Hectare</OPTION>
    <OPTION VALUE="0.00064516">Inch^2</OPTION>
    <OPTION VALUE="2589988.11034">Mile^2</OPTION>
    <OPTION VALUE="1000000">Kilometre^2</OPTION>    
    <OPTION VALUE=" 0.83612736">Yard^2</OPTION>

    </SELECT>
    <br>


<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE=" Calculate " 
       onClick="calcstress(this.form)" >
<input type="reset" value="Clear" style="margin-left:.5cm">

    <br><br>


Result:<br><br>

Stress:
<INPUT TYPE="text" SIZE="12" maxlength="15" VALUE="" NAME="result"> Newton / Meter<sup>2</sup>

    JAVASCRIPT:

    function calcstress(){
            var form = document.stress;
            var i = form.forceunits.selectedIndex;
            var forceunitsvalue = form.forceunits.options[i].value; 
            var j = form.areaunits.selectedIndex;
            var areaunitsvalue = form.areaunits.options[j].value;


            var f = form.force.value;

            var a = form.area.value;



            var result = (f * forceunitsvalue) / (a * areaunitsvalue);


            form.result.value = roundoff(result,7);

         return true;
        }



        function roundoff(x,y){             
          x = parseFloat(x);
          y = parseFloat(y);
          x = Math.round(x * Math.pow(10,y))/Math.pow(10,y);
          return x;
        }



        function calcforce(){
            var form = document.force;
            var i = form.stressunits.selectedIndex;
            var stressunitsvalue = form.stressunits.options[i].value; 
            var j = form.areaunits.selectedIndex;
            var areaunitsvalue = form.areaunits.options[j].value;


            var s = form.stress.value;

            var a = form.area.value;



            var result = (s * stressunitsvalue) * (a * areaunitsvalue);


            form.result.value =result;

         return true;
        }



        function roundoff(x,y){             
          x = parseFloat(x);
          y = parseFloat(y);
          x = Math.round(x * Math.pow(10,y))/Math.pow(10,y);
          return x;
        }




        function calcarea(){
            var form = document.area;
            var i = form.forceunits.selectedIndex;
            var forceunitsvalue = form.forceunits.options[i].value; 
            var j = form.stressunits.selectedIndex;
            var stressunitsvalue = form.stressunits.options[j].value;


            var f = form.force.value;

            var s = form.stress.value;



             var result = (f * forceunitsvalue) / (s * stressunitsvalue);


            form.result.value = result;

         return true;
        }



        function roundoff(x,y){             
          x = parseFloat(x);
          y = parseFloat(y);
          x = Math.round(x * Math.pow(10,y))/Math.pow(10,y);
          return x;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily make charts using google charts:
 Just add following CDN in your html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

Then make your data appropriate to charts data.
like:

```
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['City', '2010 Population', '2000 Population'],
        ['New York City, NY', 8175000, 8008000],
        ['Los Angeles, CA', 3792000, 3694000],
        ['Chicago, IL', 2695000, 2896000],
        ['Houston, TX', 2099000, 1953000],
        ['Philadelphia, PA', 1526000, 1517000]
```

Here is the [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sajadhaibat/eL2gbfha/3/)

Comment: Here, let me simplify what I'm looking for, then I will implement it into the bigger picture. I created this on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/avanhout13/4ayfxL16/66/ - I am looking to retrieve the output data and put it on a chart. Example: 10/5=2. I just want the number 2 to be graphed/plotted.